# find class in which another class is contained in

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class Packet which contains a Header object.

From the header object, can i find out the particular packet object it belongs to?

Is there any generic method for me to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
class Packet
{
    private Header header;
    public Header Header
    {
        get { return this.header; }
        set
        {
            this.header = value;
            this.header.Packet = this;
        }
    }
}

class Header
{
    public Packet Packet { get; set; }
}
```